# SQOOP - Export ORC format table in hive to DB2 database

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying below code to export table in orc format in hive to DB2 database.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:db2://*****:*****/DV --username test --password test11 –-table DEP.Table1
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for export:
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -table
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: DEP.Table1
```

Sqoop Version: Sqoop 1.4.6-mapr

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please check symbols before `table`: it looks that the first symbol (`–`) is [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) while the second is [hyphen minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus).

Try this command:

> sqoop export --connect jdbc:db2://*****:*****/DV --username test --password test11 --table DEP.Table1